# Execution default of goal de.juplo:hibernate4-maven-plugin:1.1.0:export failed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, hibernate-4.x

I am trying to execute hibernate4-maven-plugin with Oracle using the folowing configuration in my pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>de.juplo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>export</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/schema.sql</outputFile>
        <format>true</format>
        <force>true</force>
        <delimiter>;</delimiter>
        <type>CREATE</type>
        <target>SCRIPT</target>
        <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
        <hibernateDialect>org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        </hibernateDialect>
    </configuration>
<!-- not working
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial.thirdparty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>             
-->
</plugin>
```

but Eclipse shows the following error, saying java.sql.Date is missing :

```
Execution default of goal de.juplo:hibernate4-maven-plugin:1.1.0:export failed: 
A required class was missing while executing 
de.juplo:hibernate4-maven-plugin:1.1.0:export: java/sql/Date
```

I wonder why this is a problem as java.sql.Date is included in the JDK (rt.jar)

I tried to add the dependency to a jar containing java.sql.Date (org.xerial.thirdparty.jdbc-api) but without success.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my IDE to Spring Tools Suite 3.9.2.RELEASE, migrate the workspace and the error has gone :)